# How to copy a non-pointer value to a pointer indirected value via reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I want the `Set` method below to set the `APtr` field of a passed in `B` struct to a value that gets passed in by value, i.e. without a pointer indirection.

For that to work via go reflection, I will probably have to copy that value to a new location that I have the address of? Either way, how can I get this to work? What I have is a working version for non-pointers values.

```
type A struct {
    AnInt int
}

type B struct {
    AnA   A
    APtr *A
}

func Set(strukt interface{}, fieldName string, newFieldValue interface{}) {
    struktValueElem := reflect.ValueOf(strukt).Elem()
    field := struktValueElem.FieldByName(fieldName)
    newFieldValueValue := reflect.ValueOf(newFieldValue)
    if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        // ?? implement me
    } else { // not a pointer? more straightforward:
        field.Set(newFieldValueValue)
    }
}

func main() {
    aB := B{}
    anA := A{4}
    Set(&aB, "AnA", anA) // works
    Set(&aB, "APtr", anA) // implement me
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6tcmbXxBcIm

Comment: Is this an option? Set(&aB, "APtr", &anA) This works with  field.Set(newFieldValueValue)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/B6vOONQ-RXO

Comment: @mkopriva +1 Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func Set(strukt interface{}, fieldName string, newFieldValue interface{}) {
    struktValueElem := reflect.ValueOf(strukt).Elem()
    field := struktValueElem.FieldByName(fieldName)
    newFieldValueValue := reflect.ValueOf(newFieldValue)
    if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rt := field.Type() // type *A
        rt = rt.Elem()     // type A

        rv := reflect.New(rt) // value *A
        el := rv.Elem()       // value A (addressable)

        el.Set(newFieldValueValue) // el is addressable and has the same type as newFieldValueValue (A), Set can be used
        field.Set(rv)              // field is addressable and has the same type as rv (*A), Set can be used
    } else { // not a pointer? more straightforward:
        field.Set(newFieldValueValue)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jgEK_rKbgO9

https://play.golang.org/p/B6vOONQ-RXO (compact)

Comment: I'm glad you found them helpful @EugeneBeresovsky.